# getting values in pop up window

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a struts time picker in my parent page like

```
<sx:datetimepicker id="value1" name="value1" label="Format (dd-MMM-yyyy)" 
   displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" value="" />

<sx:datetimepicker id="value2" name="value2" label="Format (dd-MMM-yyyy)" 
   displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" value="" />
```

and on submit i am calling a pop up window on submit as

```
<s:submit value="submit" name="submit" onClick="JavaScript:Popup();"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">   

    function Popup() {
        var value1= document.getElementById('value1').value;
        var newUrl = 'jsp/popup.jsp?value1='+value1;
        popupWindow = window
                .open(newUrl,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=670,left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,addressbar=no')}
</script>
```

and in the pop up window i am trying to get the value as

```
<p>${param.value1}</p>
```

But i am not getting value1 in the pop up window. i am getting value as undefined

Any idea?

Comment: Are you creating the URL correctly? `jsp/popup.jsp?value1= & value2=` seems odd.

Comment: You should pass through an Action instead of calling a JSP directly. You should return false too from the onclick handler, or in addition to the javascript function, a submit to the default form action will be performed (or change the place where to put your javascript, like an `<a>` tag instead of an `<submit/>` tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and how exactly are passing the data? I think you are getting nothing because you are sending nothing. You could simply do this:

- create a new function
- read the values of those two fields
- compose the new url using those vales
- call window.open using the new url

Comment: actually i missed appending this, reading it as var value1= document.getElementById('value1') and encodeURIComponent(value1).value; to my url but at pop up window i am getting it as undefined, any idea .

Comment: but when are you assigning those variables? as far as i see, you are not attaching any parameters. I'm expecting something like this:

    var firstValue = document.getElementById('value1');
    var secondValue = document.getElementById('value2');
    var newUrl = 'jsp/popup.jsp?value1='+firstValue+' &     value2='+secondValue+ ...
    window.open(newUrl, ...)

Comment: yes i am doing exactly that but i am getting value1 as undefined, has it anything to do with that values are of date type..

Comment: you might check the generated html and a dom explorer such as the one in chrome (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/?hl=fr) or firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Comment: @curious If the code in your question isn't the code you're actually using, please edit the question so we can see what you're *really* doing.

Comment: could you try by placing your script block at the end of your page?

Comment: some syntax mistake was there in the url appending its been resolved now i did like this var value1= document.getElementById('value1').value;
 var newUrl = 'jsp/popup.jsp?value1="+value1+"&value2="+value2;
 popupWindow = window
   .open(newUrl,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=670,left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,addressbar=no')